# How to prevent automatic TextView word wrapping while allowing manual word wrapping

Tags: android, textview

I have a string with several `\n` line breaks in it:

```
'abc \n abcabcabc abcabc \nabcabc
```

I want my `TextView` to show the string **as is**, with exactly those line breaks that are in the string. The `TextView` should not add additional line breaks, and it should not remove any.

I'm using the following:

```
textView.setMaxLines(4);
textView.setSingleLine(false);
```

but the `TextView` renders the second line split into two lines since it is too long to be displayed in a single line.

Removing `setSingleLine(false)` leads to the `TextView` rendering everything in one line.

Setting `setMaxLines(3)` leads to the `TextView` rendering only the first two lines (on three lines). The fourth line is not rendered anymore.

**Any hints?**

Comment: Have you tried having multiple textviews with singleline set to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try just using html and forgo using `setMaxLines` or `setSingleLine` :

```
    TextView foo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
    foo.setText(Html.fromHtml("<nobr>abc </nobr><br/><nobr> abcabcabc abcabc </nobr><br/><nobr>abcabc</nobr>"));
```

Comment: or just use a ListView to display a list of TextView with `setSingleLine` for each line.

Comment: Using a ListView worked okay, but your HTML approach did not make any difference.